# Adding regular chain to nftables "Operation not supported"

Tags: linux, nftables

Syntax to add regular chain to `nftables` is:

```
add chain [family] <table_name> <chain_name> [{ [policy <policy> ;] [comment "text comment about this chain" ;] }]
```

I run the command as follows:
assumes there is ip `client` table, modify as needed to test.

```
sudo nft -i
add chain ip client test { policy accept; }
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Could not process rule: Operation not supported
add chain ip client test { policy accept; }
```

In this output error markers (^^^^^^^) are below `policy accept`

Here is output of `uname -r` and `nftables --version` respectively:

```
6.1.0-17-amd64
nftables v1.0.6 (Lester Gooch #5)
```

I'm working on Debian 12 (bookworm)

Comment: The nftables.org documentation article [Configuring chains](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains)
shows a somewhat different syntax. This example seems similar to yours : `nft 'add chain ip foo output { type filter hook output priority 0 ; policy accept; }'`. Try it to see.

Comment: @harrymc this works but it's not the same thing, please scroll down to `Adding regular chains` regular chains are unhooked.

Comment: The documentation also show `add chain inet` and not `add chain ip`.

Comment: Documentation mentions `family` both `inet` and `ip` are families, `inet` means both `ip` and `ip6` so that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`policy` can only be specified for chains that are invoked directly by a hook, i.e. which need some kind of "final" rule in case a packet reaches the end of the chain and has nowhere else to go.

If it's a chain that doesn't have a hook attached but will only be jumped to from another chain, then it cannot have a policy – the behavior in that case is always "return back to the previous chain".

This is mostly identical to iptables behavior.

Comment: That makes sense, but why does the syntax then says we can specify `policy` is it mistake in docs?

Comment: I'd go for "mistake in docs", as the source code seems pretty deliberate in only allowing base chains to have policy – the kernel specifically has an is_base_chain() check.

Comment: I'll accept your explanation, the only thing that doesn't make sense is if you want that chain to drop, then you need to create a drop rule in it. having a policy would mean no need for drop rule.

Comment: I don't think it was ever intended as a means of reducing rules... Does it make a difference though? It's one statement either way?